# Having trouble listening for socket io events in child class?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Hey guys I am working on a game. The way it works is when a Tv connects to the server
a room is created. A mobile client (phone user) is then able to join that room.
below you will find pseudo code demonstrating logic and structure.

I have refactored my code to make use of a Namespace class and a Room Class.

In the namespace class I want to only listen for connections made by either a tv client or mobile phone user client.
And in the Room class I want to make sure I only run code for X set of events.
With that being said. The events inside the Room class do not seem to be running. In this example the 'player-ready-event' is not running.

```
class Namespace {
  rooms = [];
  constructor() {
    const io = new ioServer(); // create socket io server etc etc

    // establish  on connection listener
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      // when a tv client connects create a room
      socket.on("tv-connect-event", () => {
        const newRoom = new Room(socket);
        this.rooms.push(newRoom);
      });
      // some other presently-not-so-important logic
      socket.on("mobile-connect-event", () => {});
    });
  }
}

class Room {
  playerState = {};
  constructor(socket) {
// here we listen to player-ready event
    socket.on("player-ready-event", (userId) => {
      this.playerState[userId] = {ready:true};
    });
  }
}
```

I have validated that on the client code, the 'player-ready-event' is being emitted. But I cant pinpoint why the event doesn't reach the Room instance.
Any thoughts on this design?

Comment: `this.playerState[userId]` is `undefined`

Comment: Are you sure the `tv-connect-event` event is being emitted? Add `console.log()` calls to each of the listener functions to see how far you're getting.

Comment: @Konrad thanks but in my real code I take care of that. In this example the code event is not firing.

Comment: Instead of posting pseudo-code, post the actual code. Maybe something got lost when you translated it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks but this is as close to my real code as you can get without having to post functions and files.  I have a feeling it has to do with the passing the socket as a prop in the constructor but am not entirely sure.

Comment: The way you're passing the socket seems good to me. Is it possible that the real code is using traditional functions instead of arrow functions? That will change what `this` refers to.

Comment: @Barmar so do you think it is fine that i am running socket.on in the constructor of the room class?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Barmar new clue:  inside the constructor for the room I console log the socket and I looked at it carefully and I have some interesting findings. The socket object had a property called "_events". and within that I only see my tv-connect and mobile-connect events.   therefor no 'player-ready-event' in that socket object. Remember that event is created afterwards inside the constructor of room.

Comment: Are you doing that before or after `socket.on("player-ready-event")`?

Comment: Passing a socket around isn't an issue. I'd make sure it's the **correct** socket and you're not ending up w/ additional rooms (and who knows where/how `Namespace` is being handled). It's unlikely there's enough context here to be able to help much.

Comment: @Barmar . Oh youre right. I console logged it before. my mistake. I reposition the log and now I do see it inside the "_events".  Still no event gets called for 'player-ready-event' I appreciate your help.

Comment: I suspect the problem is on the side that's supposed to be triggering the events, the handlers look ok.

Comment: @Barmar In the namespace class for testing I added the 'player-ready-event' listener and I confirm it does get called there. But not in the Room class ( which we have just confirmed does have proper reference to the socket instance ). I feel I will learn some value-able lesson once this is solved haha.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would make a difference where you add the event listener.

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you add the socket as a property of the `Room` object, so you can inspect it later.

Comment: @barmar I guess now I am rethinking my design. Is it even efficient for all the rooms to have reference to the socket object? because what if there are 100 rooms ( 100 game sessions ) and 1 event gets fired. It will run on all the rooms ( or with a validation, It would have to run 100 validations ).    maybe an alt solution would be on the 1 namespace instance listen to X events, and call the function on the correct room with the roomId provided in the payload?

Comment: I was assuming that each room has its own socket, but I now see that's not true. So the right design would be for the Namespace to manage the socket, figure out which room a message is for, then call methods on that room.

Comment: @Barmar yeah. In my project a room I guess is an abstraction. I still would prefer to manage room-specific 'events' in the room class rather than the namespace class. Im going to experiment with singleton property inside the room class so to Ideally establish 1 event listener and using the payload figure out which room the message belongs to. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Barmar Hey so I been trying to solve the mystery and I just found out something. The reason that the 'player-ready-event' is not being called is because in the room constructor we pass the *tv client* socket.   So basically only the tv client can talk with that socket about the "player-ready-event". the mobile client cannot. I will update you with more in abit.